# Complementary filter (Gyro + accel) with Android

Tags: android, filter, tracking, accelerometer, gyroscope

Recently I have made some research to use both the accelerometer + Gyroscope to use those senser to track a smartphone without the help of the GPS (see this post) 
[Indoor Positioning System based on Gyroscope and Accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499959/indoor-positioning-system-based-on-gyroscope-and-accelerometer)

For that purpose I will need my orientation (angle (pitch, roll etc..)) so here what i have done so far:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0) {
    if (arg0.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
    {
        accel[0] = arg0.values[0];
         accel[1] = arg0.values[1];
   accel[2] = arg0.values[2];
   pitch = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(accel[1], Math.sqrt(Math.pow(accel[2], 2) + Math.pow(accel[0], 2))));

  tv2.setText("Pitch: " + pitch + "\n" + "Roll: " + roll);

   } else if (arg0.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE )
{
  if (timestamp != 0) {
  final float dT = (arg0.timestamp - timestamp) * NS2S;         
  angle[0] += arg0.values[0] * dT;
  filtered_angle[0] = (0.98f) * (filtered_angle[0] + arg0.values[0] * dT) + (0.02f)* (pitch);
   }        
   timestamp = arg0.timestamp;
 }
}
```

Here I'm trying to angle (just for testing) from my accelerometer (pitch), from integration the gyroscope_X trough time  filtering it with a complementary filter

filtered_angle[0] = (0.98f) * (filtered_angle[0] + gyro_x * dT) + (0.02f)* (pitch)

**with dT  begin more or less 0.009 secondes**

But I don't know why but my angle are not really accurate...when the device is position flat on the table (Screen facing up)

```
Pitch (angle fromm accel) = 1.5 (average) 
Integrate gyro = 0 to growing (normal it's drifting) 
filtered gyro angle = 1.2
```

and when I lift the phone of 90° (see the screen is facing the wall in front of me)

```
Pitch (angle fromm accel) = 86 (MAXIMUM) 
Integrate gyro = he is out ok its normal 
filtered gyro angle = 83 (MAXIMUM)
```

So the angles never reach 90 ??? Even if I try to lift the phone a bit more...
Why doesn't it going until 90° ? Are my calculation wrong? or is the quality of the sensor crap?

AN other thing that I'm wondering it is that: with Android I don't "read out" the value of the sensor but I'm notified when they change. The problem is that as you see in the code the Accel and Gyro share the same method.... so when I compute the filtered angle I will take the pitch of the accel measure 0.009 seconds before, no ? Is that maybe the source of my problem?

Thank you !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Indoor Positioning System based on Gyroscope and Accelerometer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499959/indoor-positioning-system-based-on-gyroscope-and-accelerometer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can only [repeat myself.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499959/indoor-positioning-system-based-on-gyroscope-and-accelerometer/7500306#7500306)

You get position by integrating the linear acceleration twice but **the error is horrible. It is useless in practice.** In other words, you are trying to solve the impossible.

What you actually can do is to track just the orientation.

Roll, pitch and yaw are evil, do not use them. Check in [the video I already recommended](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k), at 38:25.

Here is an [excellent tutorial](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9rLLz1XQKmaZTlQdV81QjNoZTA) on how to track orientation with gyros and accelerometers.

Similar questions that you might find helpful:

[track small movements of iphone with no GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6158176/341970)
[What is the real world accuracy of phone accelerometers when used for positioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6027724/341970)
[how to calculate phone's movement in the vertical direction from rest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6291110/341970)
[iOS: Movement Precision in 3D Space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5550453/341970)
[How to use Accelerometer to measure distance for Android Application Development](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6352681/341970)
[Distance moved by Accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6645126/341970)
[How can I find distance traveled with a gyroscope and accelerometer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6647314/341970)

Comment: Thank you for your help, and sorry to make your repeat stuff..
Indeed the gentlnav tutorial is really nice! I have just read it quickly and it explaines the DCM quite well I'm gonna read it more carefully

I found a similar question on stackoverflow where you talk about the same tutorial and you say that you use it your human motion sensing. So that means that you successfully manage to get nice orientation using DCM ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314217/gyro-accelerometer-magnetometer-and-kalman-filter

Thank you

Comment: @Alexis No problem, and good luck! Yes, I have a C++ implementation, but its not too difficult to write your own in Java for Android. Perhaps there are exisiting applications unfortunately I do not known any. Is just orientation enough for your application?

Comment: As it's just a project for my school, I was just interested to know if it was possible.. after lot of readings I found out that it's not :) or if it is is way ahead my math understandings... So I'm just gonna change a bit and try to play with gyro + accel to only get orientation :)

Comment: I just found that: http://www.diydrones.com/profiles/blogs/a-simple-deadreckoning it's use the DCM + deadreckoning to track a plane (he is intergrating twice to get the position but i didn't understant how he is correcting the result)

Comment: @Alexis I did not check the details but it seems to me his algorithm is based on the GPS and the IMU is used to "fill in the gaps." Yes, you can do that with the Kalman filter but in your question you say you do not have/use GPS.

Comment: @Ali thanks for your explanation,Can you guide me about this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137239/get-moving-device-direction-without-gps

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a tutorial on the use of the Complementary Filter for oriëntation tracking with gyroscope and accelerometer: http://www.pieter-jan.com/node/11 maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I test your code and found that probably the scale factor is not consistent. 
Convert the pitch to 0-pi gives better result. 
In my test, the filtered result is ~90 degrees.

```
pitch = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(accel[1], Math.sqrt(Math.pow(accel[2], 2) + Math.pow(accel[0],   2))));
pitch = pitch*PI/180.f;

filtered_angle = weight * (filtered_angle + event.values[0] * dT) + (1.0f-weight)* (pitch);
```

Answer (score -1):

i tried and this will give you  angle 90...

```
filtered_angle = (filtered_angle / 83) * 90;
```