# Kalman tracking: process and update equation

Tags: kalman-filter

I want to track a rectangular ABCD using Kalman filter. I saw many people use position and velocity as state vector. Can I use position of point A, the length and width of the rectangular as state vector? Therefore, the process and update equation are:

[image]

Is this correct?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Why is the covariance matrix an identity matrix? Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5411484/341970

Comment: Hi Ali, I think the covariance matrix is a constant multiply with an identity matrix. I just follow matlab example.

Comment: OK, it is possible. But you still have to determine that constant, see on the above link. The process and measurement noise is the product of the corresponding constant AND the identity matrix, please fix your equations.

Comment: I do not know how to determine that constant. However, please have a look at here: http://www.kxcad.net/cae_MATLAB/toolbox/dspblks/ref/kalmanfilter.html  <----Matlab determine constant such as 10 and o.05 without any rule. I dont understand why

Comment: By the way, I could not find useful information from the link you gave.

Comment: As for the link I gave, it is concluded that "determining the variance is 100% experimental." Please re-read it. As for the MATLAB example, they must have obtained those constants by experiments too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that model, but it will not be very useful. The system matrix A has to model the behavior. You model basically says "there are values which do not change". The Kalman filter will take some weighted average of your measurements because you told it the value wouldn't change.

You said you wanted to do *tracking*, that implies some movement. In this case, you want to have a velocity in there. Your model will evolve from "estimate my constant" to "estimate content velocity motion".

Depending on your specific application, constant accelerated motion might make more sense, in this case your state vector will have at least 6 elements (two-dimansional case) (x, y, x_velocity, ..., y_acceleration) and your system matrix becomes slightly more complex. You can always add the length and width as additional state variables.